# ElasticSearch Health Check via POST call

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dsl

I want to fetch the Elasticsearch Cluster Health via POST call, Is it possible ?

I know how to get it via GET call, but i have access to POST only.

Comment: It's funny, in restricted environments, usually only GET is allowed, but you have only POST... I'm curious to know the reason why

Comment: I dont think reason will anyhow help to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

Retrieving the cluster health is only supported by GET calls as it generally makes no sense to "read" data via a POST call (at least in well-behaved REST services):

Either `GET _cat/health`([view source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/cat/RestHealthAction.java#L38))

or `GET _cluster/health`([view source](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/admin/cluster/RestClusterHealthAction.java#L44))

Comment: Then I'm afraid, you'll have to find another solution if POST is really a constraint. Again it doesn't make sense to GET information via a POST call.